# how to get Location from google in ios?

Tags: ios7.1

I want to do something like this in my iOS app. I have a text box. When user type a rode, country,city or anything the full address or should appear in a drop down box. I uploaded a picture of a web site. This what I want to do in ios. How can I do that? Please help me

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using google map's [SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/) which provides a large reference/documentation. Not much else to say

Sent from iPad so please excuse my typos